# How to match or make a comparison of TableColumn text with TaskDay value of object StaffTimesheet stored in ObservableArrayList?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx

There are 4 java files - SargonVenture, TimesheetScene, StaffTimesheetAccessor, and StaffTimesheet.

SargonVenture is the main program that launch the program and display the TimesheetScene as following:
[TimesheetSceneImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCx3k.png)

StaffTimesheetAccessor is the database connector that performs query and store the result of query into object of StaffTimesheet which are then stored in observableArrayList().

In the TimesheetScene, what I want to do is that (If TableColumn of dayListColumn is equal to TaskDay value of object StaffTimesheet stored in observableArrayList, then it will display the TaskNumberOfHours at those respective columns of dayListColumn). The error section is commented in TimesheetScene file.

The codes are below.

SargonVenture.java:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class SargonVenture extends Application {

private static Stage primaryStage;
private static Scene scene;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    SargonVenture.primaryStage = primaryStage;

    TimesheetScene timesheetScene = new TimesheetScene();

    scene = new Scene(timesheetScene);

    primaryStage.setTitle("");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public void setStage(Stage stage)
{
    primaryStage = stage;
}

public static Stage getStage()
{
    return primaryStage;
}

public static void setNewScene(Scene scene)
{
    SargonVenture.scene = scene;
}

public static Scene getTheScene()
{
    return scene;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

TimesheetScene.java:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;


public class TimesheetScene extends BorderPane{

private final TableView<StaffTimesheet> tableView = new TableView<>();

private final ComboBox<String> comboBoxStaffName;
private final ComboBox<String> comboBoxMonth;
private final ComboBox<String> comboBoxYear;
Button buttonSearch;

private final StaffTimesheetAccessor dataTimesheetAccessor;

public TimesheetScene() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

    dataTimesheetAccessor = new StaffTimesheetAccessor("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/rka?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "291222");

    GridPane gridPane1 = new GridPane();
    gridPane1.setHgap(10);
    GridPane gridPane2 = new GridPane();
    gridPane2.setHgap(10);
    GridPane gridPane3 = new GridPane();
    gridPane3.setHgap(10);


    comboBoxStaffName = new ComboBox<>();
    comboBoxStaffName.getItems().addAll(dataTimesheetAccessor.getStaffName());
    gridPane1.add(new Label("Staff Name: "), 0, 0);
    gridPane1.add(comboBoxStaffName, 1, 0);


    comboBoxMonth = new ComboBox<>();
    comboBoxMonth.getItems().addAll("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12");
    comboBoxMonth.setValue("01");
    gridPane2.add(new Label("Month: "), 0, 0);
    gridPane2.add(comboBoxMonth, 1, 0);


    comboBoxYear = new ComboBox<>();
    comboBoxYear.getItems().addAll(dataTimesheetAccessor.getYear());
    gridPane3.add(new Label("Year: "), 0, 0);
    gridPane3.add(comboBoxYear, 1, 0);


    HBox hbox1 = new HBox(100);
    hbox1.getChildren().addAll(gridPane1, gridPane2, gridPane3);
    hbox1.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));


    buttonSearch = new Button("Search");

    HBox hbox2 = new HBox(40);
    hbox2.getChildren().addAll(hbox1, buttonSearch);
    hbox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hbox2.setPadding(new Insets(20, 50, 20, 50));
    setTop(hbox2);


    TableColumn dayColumn = new TableColumn("Day");
    tableView.getColumns().addAll(dayColumn);


    TableColumn[] dayListColumn = new TableColumn[31];
    int x = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < dayListColumn.length; i++)
    {

        String y = String.valueOf(x);
        dayListColumn[i] = new TableColumn(y);
        dayColumn.getColumns().add(dayListColumn[i]);

        // HERE IS THE ERROR
        if(dayListColumn[i].getText().equals(dataTimesheetAccessor.getStaffDayHourList().get(i).getTaskDay())){
            dayListColumn[i].setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("TaskNumberOfHours"));
        }
        x=x+1;
    }

    buttonSearch.setOnAction(e ->{
        String staffName = comboBoxStaffName.getValue();
        String monthOfTaskDay = comboBoxMonth.getValue();
        String yearOfTaskDay = comboBoxYear.getValue();
        try {
            tableView.setItems(dataTimesheetAccessor.getStaffDayHour(staffName, monthOfTaskDay, yearOfTaskDay));
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TimesheetScene.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    });

    setCenter(tableView);
}

}
```

StaffTimesheetAccessor.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;


public class StaffTimesheetAccessor {

private final Connection connection;

ObservableList<StaffTimesheet> staffDayHourList;

public StaffTimesheetAccessor(String driverClassName, String dbURL, String user, String password) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    Class.forName(driverClassName);
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, password);
}

public void shutdown() throws SQLException {
    if(connection != null)
    {
        connection.close();
    }
}

public ObservableList<StaffTimesheet> getStaffDayHour(String staffName, String monthOfTaskDay, String yearOfTaskDay) throws SQLException{
    String nameOfStaff = staffName;
    String month = monthOfTaskDay;
    String year = yearOfTaskDay;
    try(
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT DAY(Timesheet.TaskDay), ROUND((Timesheet.TaskNumberOfHours + (Timesheet.TaskNumberOfMinutes/60)), 2)\n" +
                                                        "FROM Clients\n" +
                                                        "INNER JOIN Timesheet ON Clients.ClientID = Timesheet.ClientID\n" +
                                                        "INNER JOIN Task ON Task.TaskID = Timesheet.TaskID\n" +
                                                        "INNER JOIN Staff ON Timesheet.StaffID = Staff.StaffID\n" +
                                                        "WHERE Staff.StaffName = '" + nameOfStaff + "'\n" +
                                                        "AND MONTH(Timesheet.TaskDay) = " + month + "\n" +
                                                        "AND YEAR(Timesheet.TaskDay) = " + year + ";");
    )
    {
        staffDayHourList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        while(resultSet.next()){
            String TaskDay = resultSet.getString(1);
            String TaskNumberOfHours = resultSet.getString(2);
            staffDayHourList.add(new StaffTimesheet(TaskDay, TaskNumberOfHours));
        }
        return staffDayHourList;
    }
}

public ObservableList<StaffTimesheet> getStaffDayHourList(){
    return staffDayHourList;
}



public ObservableList<String> getStaffName() throws SQLException{
    try(
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select StaffName from Staff");
    ){
        ObservableList<String> staffNameList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        while(resultSet.next()){
            String StaffName = resultSet.getString(1);
            staffNameList.add(StaffName);
        }
        return staffNameList;
    }
}

public ObservableList<String> getYear() throws SQLException{
    try(
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select DISTINCT(YEAR(TaskDay)) from Timesheet");
    ){
        ObservableList<String> timesheetYearList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        while(resultSet.next()){
            String timesheetYear = resultSet.getString(1);
            timesheetYearList.add(timesheetYear);
        }
        return timesheetYearList;
    }
}

}
```

StaffTimesheet.java:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;


public class StaffTimesheet{

private SimpleStringProperty TaskDay;
private SimpleStringProperty TaskNumberOfHours;



public StaffTimesheet(String TaskDay, String TaskNumberOfHours){
    this.TaskDay = new SimpleStringProperty(TaskDay);
    this.TaskNumberOfHours = new SimpleStringProperty(TaskNumberOfHours);
}


public String getTaskDay(){
    return TaskDay.get();
}

public void setTaskDay(String TaskDay){
    this.TaskDay.set(TaskDay);
}

public String getTaskNumberOfHours(){
    return TaskNumberOfHours.get();
}

public void setTaskNumberOfHours(String TaskNumberOfHours){
    this.TaskNumberOfHours.set(TaskNumberOfHours);
}

}
```

The query result is as following: [Query Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC9xa.png)

Comment: tip 1, don't write SQL injection vulnerable code. Tip 2 - put results on stack overflow rather than an offsite image site. Tip 3 - rather than getting into an ArrayList, write a query to fetch your desired result directly.

Comment: I don't know if I agree with @danblack third tip. Just my opinion. I think it's okay to put your results in an `ArrayList`. I am against using an `ObservableList` at this point though. I think the  `ObservableList` needs to be created in the `Class` the sets the items. That way if you need to query the DB, you can set the data of the current `ObservableList` instead of setting a new `ObservableList`.